# duvida com ajax e angular

Tags: ajax, angularjs, json, http

tenho meu back-end, na minha controller tenho um metodo

```
salvarBairro(string dados)
```

estou usando angular, esse cara aqui chama meu metodo salvarBairro do back

```
 $scope.AddBairro = function (bairro) {
            $http.post("http://localhost:23714/Bairro/save", bairro).success(function (data) {

            });
```

meu metodo do back só consegue capturar o json enviado se o parametro for do tipo BairroModel, ex:

```
salvarBairro(BairroModel dados)
```

caso o parametro seja do tipo string, recebe null, mesmo a view enviando o json. Mas eu preciso forçar o metodo receber uma string, pois alem dos dados do bairro, eu quero enviar outos dados, é possivel isso?

- como poderia fazer para enviar mais de um json ?
- como poderia forçar o metodo do back-end a receber o json enviado, declarando os parametros como string  - salvarBairro(string dados)

Comment: Ta usando qual linguagem no back-end?

Comment: c# / mvc - com entity framework

Comment: Entendi, como não entendo muito da tecnologia vou falar como eu faço usando java, talvez assim fique mais fácil de você entender.

Answer (score 1):

Como está usando C# não posso te ajudar 100% porém vou responder da forma que faço algo semelhante com `Java+Vraptor` talvez possa te ajudar.

Controller no back-end:

```
@Get
@Path("/listar/{paginaInicio}")
public void listarTodos(Integer paginaInicio) {
    result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(grupoDAO.listar(paginaInicio, 5)).serialize();
}
```

Repare que eu estou passando um atributo direto na `URL` e recebendo ele como parâmetro em meu método `listarTodos`

Então no front-end tenho o seguinte serviço:

```
 var _getGroups = function(paginaInicio){
    return $http.get(config.baseURL + "/EtiquetaAPI/grupo/listar/" + paginaInicio);
  };
```

Nesse serviço eu concateno o atributo a `URL`, diferente de quando passo um objeto

Comment: vou tentar fazer isso, mas quando tem q passar uma qtde muito grande de dados, nao seria inviavel passa na url?

Comment: certamente, vou ver se acho outra maneira de passar esses dados

Comment: Tente fazer isso:  `$http.post("http://localhost:23714/Bairro/save", JSON.stringify(bairro))`

Comment: veja se funciona

Comment: nao funcionou... recebe nulo

Comment: fiz esse video , se puder ver ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWJM6zpFRUg

Answer (score 1):

A principio na minha opinião o .NET ajuda nessa parte convertendo o objeto JSON em objeto C# automaticamente por isso o `BairroModel` ou outra classe funcionam . Basicamente você está abrindo mão de uma informação estruturada (objeto server-side) por uma menos estruturada (texto querystring). Por fim esta solução só está aumentando a complexidade da sua solução.

Mas colocando essa observação à parte para conseguir o que voce deseja, primeiro voce tem que transformar o objeto em JSON numa string no Javascript `JSON.stringify(bairro)` motificar a forma que será feita a solicitação para o padrão de formulário HTMLe passar ela na solicitação.

Tente da seguinte forma AngularJS:

```
$http({
    url: 'http://localhost:23714/Bairro/save',
    method: 'POST',
    data: { dados: JSON.stringify(bairro) },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
```

No Seu MVC adapte seu método `ActionResult` para isso:

```
salvarBairro(string dados)
```

Comment: Rogerio, nao funcionou, veja nesse video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yff0snARJqQ
 em relação a sua observação, pensei em criar uma classe auxiliar, e todos os meus modelos herdaria essa classe, q vc axa ?

Comment: Na realidade quando uso o MVC, eu faço todas as classes e chamo elas de Request no final por exemplo. `BairroRequest` e essa classe representa apenas os valores que irão no POST, desta forma ficaria muito simples o trabalho, vboce passa o objeto direto pelo angular, sem ter que transformá-lo em string

Comment: No seu vídeo, voce chama a variável de entrada na função de `acesso`, portanto a sua variável de querystring deverá ser `acesso`e não `dados`, ou seja: `{ acesso:  JSON.stringify(bairro)  }`

Answer (score 1):

Agradeço aos colegas pelas respostas. encontrei nesse post o que eu procurava a tempos: [varios parametros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002924/how-to-send-string-over-angular-http-to-c-sharp-asp-net-backend)

entao, o meu metodo do angular ficou assim:

```
$scope.Salvar = function (checklist) {      
$http.post("http://localhost:55959/CheckList/save", { checklist: checklist, parametro1: "parametro1" })
    .success(function (data) {
        if (data == "200") {
            alert("Cadastro realizado com sucesso");
        }
        else
            alert(data);
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        alert("Erro");
    });
```

};

dessa forma, é possivel passar varios parametros, no meu exemplo ali, o meu primeiro parametro é um json, que no meu backend será convertido automaticamente para o tipo checkList, o segundo parametro é uma string. Isso abre muitas possibillidades.